# How to create global picklist from a custom object. (salesforce)

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object location contain id and name only. Is there any trick to create multi picklist from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Multi-Select PickList in the In your custom object :

If you want the pickList value available in other objects also then You can create a Global Pick List: Click on Setup Type PickList value set in Search Box and Choose it Create new Pick List value.

If you are in Salesforce Classic GO to Setup Search for Object the click on it it will open List of your custom object choose your custom object then select In Fields and Relationships Click New choose New Field as **Multi-Select** PickList. Specify the name In the PickList Value Choose from Global Pick List or You can specify its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multi-select picklist just like any other field:

Salesforce Classic -> Setup -> Create -> Objects -> MyObject -> Fields and Relationships -> New Field